# Terraform: Automate backup of infrastructure

Tags: terraform, datadog

In my company, we have Datadog dashboards and monitors which we often make changes to and thus we wish to have some version control. After discussions it was decided that Terraform is the way to go with this. I've successfully been able to manually back up our current Datadog infrastructure using Google's *Terraformer* (to import the infrastructure as resources) and Terraform's CLI commands to import the corresponding infrastructure's states. It is also possible to make changes to the resources through commands such as `terraform plan` and `terraform apply`. The manual changes to the resources can then be backed up with Git.

Now to the issue I'm having. We wish to automate the the back-up of our resources, that is, through making changes in the Datadog GUI and to have those changes be reflected in our resource files. That means the other way around of what I've managed to accomplish above. It is rather straight forward to do this manually, where one imports the infrastructure resources that have been changed using the GUI (using terraformer). If "conflicts" arise, one needs to manually remove certain resources and re-import them which I've found difficult to automate.

My question is: is there a straight forward way of automating back-up of changes made "remotely" (e.g. in the Datadog GUI) to resource files? My research for Terraform CLI's for this purpose has lead me to nothing thus far.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The point of using Terraform is to define your infrastructure as code. If you want to change it outside of that then Terraform is going to try to put it back to the way you defined it in code. I would advise against trying to have Terraform define these things and also trying to accommodate people making changes to those resources outside of the Terraform code. If that makes it painful to manage the dashboards etc then maybe Terraform isn't a good fit here for you.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Thanks for your reply! I see, that does makes sense.